# Python 3.7 TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im hoping somebody can help me out in why the function I'm writing to convert a string into a list of list of binary numbers isn't working.

```
def string2bin(str):
    bin = []
    for n in range(len(str)):
        char = ord(str[n])
        char = bin(char)
        char[2:].zfill(8)
        bin.append(list(map(int, char)))

    return bin
```

Here's the error I'm getting when running the function with these arguments.

```
string2bin('abc')

    char = bin(char)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: you overwrite `bin` at `bin = []`. later in your code at `bin(char)` you will get that error message. same goes for `str`...

Answer (score 1):

`str` is a reserved keyword in python. Use another name for your variable.

Comment: this should be a comment as it doesn't answer the OP

Comment: You are right. Unfortunately I do not have enough reputation to comment.

Answer (score 0):

`bin()` is a [Python built-in method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bin) but you named your final list `bin = []` so when you get to `char = bin(char)` you've overwritten it.

The error you get is because `bin` now refers to a list which you then try to call like a function.

Just rename `bin` to something else.

Also, `char` is not a great name for `ord(str[n])`.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined first bin as a list and then you are using it as a function.
I think you want to do `char = bin[char]` instead